# Angular 7 Http Post Request - Subscribe only catching OPTIONS response not the actual response

Tags: angular, http, post, angular7, preflight

I am sending a post request to upload a file from my angular 7 front end. The network console on chrome shows that it is sending an OPTIONS request first before sending my post request. I can also see the correct response it received to my post request. My problem is that the OPTIONS request is returning a 204 No Content error and seems to be "killing" the subscribe event. The post upload request sends back a key in the body of the response, which i need to access and so i have a subscribe event on my post request that should print out the response but all i get in the console is "error - Ok".

```
this.http.post<any>(url+this.currentTokenPublicId,formData,{observe:'response'}).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log("here");
      console.log(res);
      console.log(res.headers);
      console.log(res.body);
    },(err)=>console.log("error = "+err));
```

**UPDATE:
There seems to be some confusion based on the response i have received thus far. The post request is completed successfully. The problem is that i don't get the response from it. All i get is the message "error = Ok" because the response received is coming back as an error not a response (hence "here" is not printed). Looking at the network console in chrome, it shows that my post request is completed successfully and the key i need is returned. I just can't get it as the preflight OPTIONS post seems to be triggering the error printout and then nothing else gets printed.

Comment: Huh. 204 is not an error status. Pretty much every time I get the *"in the dev tools response comes back fine, but Angular behaves as if it didn't"* error is when something is wrong with the headers. Like: the response's actual content doesn't match the response's "content-type", or the response's type doesn't match the request's "accept".

Comment: the post request is completed successfully. The problem is that i don't get the response from it. All i get is the message "error = Ok" because the response received is coming back as an error not a response. Looking at the network console in chrome, it shows that my post request is completed successfully and the key i need is returned. I just can't get it as the preflight OPTIONS post seems to be triggering the error printout and then nothing else gets printed.

Comment: @user7856951 was there any resolution to this problem?